# How to escape slash with morphMany method?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

My model has morphMany method with class defined

```
public function relationships()
{        
    return $this->morphMany(RelationshipsModel::class, 'model', 'relation_model_type', 'model_id', 'id');
}
```

and it does not find data I expect.
Checking logs I see sql:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `relationships` 
    WHERE `relationships`.`model_id` = '1'        AND `relationships`.`relation_model_type` = 'Modules\Opportunities\Models\OpportunityModel'     AND 
...
```

and if manually to slash it, like:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `relationships` 
    WHERE `relationships`.`model_id` = '1'        AND `relationships`.`relation_model_type` = 'Modules\\Opportunities\\Models\\OpportunityModel'     AND
```

I got valid results.

I tried to modify model as :

```
return $this->morphMany(addslashes(RelationshipsModel::class), 'model', 'relation_model_type', 'model_id', 'id');
```

But I got error :

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
Cannot declare class Modules\Relationships\Models\RelationshipsModel, because the name is already in use
```

Which way is valid ?

laravel 6

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The slashes should not be the problem, since variables in the SQL statements are prepared, not inlined. In your manual try, the variable is inlined, therefore slashes are needed. I suspect there might be an other reason why data is not showing. Are you running automated tests? Are you sure correct data is present?

Comment: These are not automated tests and I suppose that   data  are correct

Comment: Try to tinker (`php artisan tinker`), get the model, and check its relationship. Tinker will show you if the relation object is correct, and what the actual result is when you perform a `->get()`. Verify the problem is actual with the relation, or in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use morph map:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types

```
Relation::morphMap([
   'Opportunity' => 'Modules\Opportunities\Models\OpportunityModel'
]);
```